# Execute powershell script with gitlab-runner on local windows machine

Tags: powershell, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, github-for-windows

I do have following setup:

- a win PC with gitlab-runner installed (working)
- a powershell script running on the same PC is starting an application
- a gitlab server to connect this local PC and starting the powershell script

Now when starting the powershell script directly from the local PC, the application starts and terminates after done - working as expected. When starting the same powershell script with the gitlab server (yml-file) then I can see that the application has been started (new process in taskmanager) but it is not running as well it never terminates.

When manually end the task I see that gitlab terminates again.

**Question:**

- what could be the root cause?
- is it possible to run the powershell script with gitlab-runner? I think there is a way with the command "exec". How does the command looks like when calling the powershell script?
- is it possible to run the application not in the background in order to see whats going on?
- others?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug with the gitlab runner on windows.
No matter which shell you configure in the config.toml the runner
will always use cmd.exe for an exec local run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `--shell` argument to override the default `cmd.exe` shell:

```
> gitlab-runner exec shell your_job --shell pwsh
```

If you run this locally in your project, it outputs to `.builds/`, so add this to your `.gitignore` because `git` will see it and think you might want to add a `submodule`.